# How can i use three blanks as a delimiter?

Tags: awk, delimiter, cut, tr

I need to set the delimiter from a : to three blanks.

So far my code is as follows:

```
cut -d f1,6,7 test | tr : '   '
```

Dont mind anything before the pipe, that is just for formatting of the file "test". It will replace the delimiter with one blank, but not three, how do i accomplish this?

Comment: `tr` is one-to-one replacement. For more than that you need something like `awk` or `sed` or almost anything else. What else have you tried?

Comment: Please specify your requirements in a way that others can follow. In it's current version the question is completely unclear.

Comment: so i have the following string:
larryjohnson:x:604:512: Larry Johnson:/home/students/larryhohnson2:/bin/bash

and what i need to do, is extract the user name, home directory, and default shell, so i used this to extract those:
cut -d f1,6,7 test,

Now i need to replace the : delimiter with three blank spaces, and thats where im stuck, im not sure which awk or sed command to use.

Comment: @Mitch Please edit your question instead of adding the explanation in comments.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
awk -F: -v OFS="   " '{print $1,$6,$7}' test
```

`-F` sets the input field separator to colon, `-v` sets the output field separator to 3 spaces, then the awk body prints the desired fields

The sed option would be

```
cut -d: -f1,6,7 test | sed 's/:/   /g'
```